# Rank of triangular matrices of special form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Am I right about the following matrices:

$$A=
\left[\begin{matrix}
x&x&x&x\\
0&x&x&x\\
0&0&0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

$$B=
\left[\begin{matrix}
x&x&x\\
0&x&x\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0&\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

($x$ denotes an arbitrary non-zero element)

that they both are rank deficient, $r(A)=2$  since it's the number of non-zero rows. $r(B)=2$, since it has two non-zero rows as well.

**The more important question (to which I need to know the correct answer to be able to understand rank decomposition) is:**

Can I write $A$ as

$$A=
\left[\begin{matrix}
T_{11}&T_{12}\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Where $T_{11}$ and $T_{12}$ are $2 \times 2$ matices which are invertible and from there I conclude $r(A)=2$?

Comment: Provided that $x \neq 0$, then you are correct that $\operatorname{rk}(A) = \operatorname{rk}(B) = 2$, but your reasoning is not quite correct.

Comment: Having only $2$ nonzero rows, shows that $\operatorname{rk}(A) \le 2$, but the rank could actually be smaller.  *The rows have to be linearly independent,* which means (for a set of size $2$) that neither is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Dear @SammyBlack : consider tossing that into an answer and pinging me so I can come back and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Something occurs to me.  When you use the symbol $x$ in various entries of the matrix, do you intend for it to stand for the same number or is it just a placeholder for some nonzero number (where each instance could be a *different* nonzero number)?

Comment: @Sammy: The latter, I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: @rschwieb: Didn't you suggest Sammy to post his comment as answer?

Comment: @Gigili Yes, thanks for pinging me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. If 
$$A=
\left[\begin{matrix}
T_{11}&T_{12}\\
0&0\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
where $T_{11},T_{12}$  are  invertible matrices then $rank(A)=2.$
It is obvious since $T_{11}$ (or $T_{12}$) is a maximal minor of $A$ with non-zero determinant. All $3 \times 3$  minors  have a zero row.

Comment: @Gigili, Thank you for correction.

Comment: You're very welcome! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Leox Could you help me, please with this similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669018/rank-of-quadratic-form ?

Answer (score 1):

Now, as an answer.

Provided that $x \neq 0$, then you are correct that $\operatorname{rk}(A) = \operatorname{rk}(B) = 2$, but your reasoning is not quite correct.

Having only $2$ nonzero rows, shows that $\operatorname{rk}(A) \le 2$, but the rank could actually be smaller.  *The rows have to be linearly independent,* which means (for a set of size $2$) that neither is a nonzero scalar multiple of the other.

---

**Edit after clarification in comments.**

Any $2 \times 2$ matrix
$$
T_{11} = \begin{bmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & * \end{bmatrix},
$$
where each $*$ represents a (possibly different) nonzero number, is invertible.  Placing this in the upper left corner, regardless of the block that you named $T_{12}$ yields
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
T_{11} & \begin{matrix} * & * \\ * & * \end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \end{bmatrix},
$$
which is necessarily of rank $2$.  Why?  The first two columns are linearly independent and span a $2$ dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ (where the last coordinate is $0$), so $\operatorname{rk}(A) \ge 2$.  The other columns are already in the span of the first two columns; hence, they contribute nothing more to the rank.

So, $\operatorname{rk}(A) = 2$.

Comment: Ping, @rschwieb.

Comment: This ping didn't reach me! Perhaps it has to be in comments where I've already spoken...